# POST-ing text and files with HTTPBuilder and MultipartEntity

Tags: grails, multipartentity

I am using groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder to POST from Grails to a PHP script. I need to attach a couple of text fields and a number of files.

I can attach a few textfields this way with great success:

```
    MultipartEntity mpc = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
    mpc.addPart("json", new StringBody(json.toString()))
```

But, when I attach a file like this, the textfields are no longer present in the request:

```
        passFiles.each() { key, value ->
            mpc.addPart(key, new InputStreamBody(value.stream, value.type, value.filename))
            System.out << value
        }
```

I think the file should be okay to add this way. Here is my trace from the above:

`[filename:icon.png, stream:java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@2747ebcb, type:image/png]`

How can I cause HTTPBuilder to make this Multipart POST as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew's comment caused me to take a better look at the HTTPClient Java API. I was able to make everything work as above like this:

1. Save a temporary copy of the stream to a file.

   ```
   def file = new File('web-app/tmpfiles/file.dat').newOutputStream()
   file << stream
   file.close()
   ```
2. Instead of using InputStreamBody, use FileBody with the path to the saved file.

   ```
   mpc.addPart(key, new FileBody(new File('web-app/tmpfiles/file.dat'), filename, type, 'UTF-8'))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

1. Did you remember to call `setEntity()` to link your request with your `MultipartEntity`?
2. Depending on the version of  Grails/Groovy you're using, you may be running into issue(s) in HTTPBuilder, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452678/groovy-httpbuilder-and-multipartentity-multipart-form-data).  That link points to a patched fork, which I haven't tried.
3. It's less than Groovy, but I've been able to accomplish a similar task from Grails with code that sticks closely to the Apache HTTPClient Java API.

Comment: 1. Yes - definitely have to call setEntity() 2. I had actually tried that fork, which caused me a lot of problems with dependecies due to my own inexperience 3. Thanks! You reminded me that Groovy is just Java.